# Bash Regex extract all text from 2nd occurence of specific character until end of line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following strings:

```
text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

with a regular expression, I want to extract:

```
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

I have tried with regex101.com the following expression: `([^:]+)(?::[^:]+){1}$`
and it worked (only for the first string)

But if I try in bash, it does not

```
echo "text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1" | sed -n "/([^:]+)(?::[^:]+){1}$/p"
```

Comment: Why regex and not a simple `cut` invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'|\([^:]*:\)\{2\}\(.*\)$|\2|' input_file
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

or

```
$ sed s'|\([^:]*:\)\{2\}||' input_file
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be much easier with `cut` without any regex:

```bash
cut -d: -f3- file

text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

Answer (score 4):

Non capture groups `(?:` are not supported in `sed` and you have to escape the `\(` `\)` `\{` `\}` and `\+`

You can repeat 2 occurrences of `:` from the start of the string and replace that with an empty string.

```
sed 's/^\([^:]\+:\)\{2\}//' file
```

Or using `sed -E` for extended regexp:

```
sed -E 's/^([^:]+:){2}//' file
```

Output

```
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

Comment: If `:` is the delimiter then `[^:]` is the complement for a single character. The question is, must the complement (s) exist?. The `+` metacharacter represents one or more of the previous character or group (group is a paren enclosed regexp) where as the `*` represents zero or more. If the field must exist use `+` otherwise use `*`.

Comment: @potong Thank you for the comment, that is correct. If there are more parts like `::` then you could use `[^:]*`

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to drag `sed` or other external programs into this; just use bash's built in regular expression matching:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

strings=(text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
         text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1)

for s in "${strings[@]}"; do
    [[ $s =~ ^([^:]*:){2}(.*) ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Heck, you don't need regular expressions in bash:

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${s#*:*:}"
```

Comment: Though if you do want to use a program, I agree `cut` is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

**awk**

```
string='ext/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text/:some_random_text:text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1'

awk -vFS=: -vOFS=: '{$1=$2="";gsub(/^::/,"")}1' <<<"$string"
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```

Answer (score 0):

absolutely no need to use anything that requires `regex-backreferences`, since the regex anchoring is right at the line head anyway :

```
mawk ++NF OFS= FS='^[^:]*:[^:]*:' 
                       
text_i_w4nt_to:k33p.until_th3_end_1
text_i_w4nt_to::k33p.until_th3_end_1
```